# How do I not allow pygame to change my screen resolution in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, pygame, wine

I've recently written a shell script which boots my Windows Python application with wine:

```
#!/bin/sh
wine data/Python/x86/python.exe loader.py 'x86'
```

While the program is running, everything works as expected. The problem is, when the SDL window is displayed, my second monitor is disabled, and the orientation of my primary monitor changes. The resolution of  my primary monitor stays the same. My question is, what can I do to disable these changes?

Installing a Linux Python interpreter is out of the question, because the solution:

1: needs to be portable
2: would currently oversize download

EDIT:

some extra info, I just recently ran it with a terminal and got:

```
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x42f3ec,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x42f46c,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:wgl:X11DRV_wglChoosePixelFormatARB unused pfAttribFList
```

not sure if this solves anything though

Comment: Your game asks for a *window* and the windows port of SDL *still* screws up your screen configuration? Crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've used it long enough to verify this was the case.
I'd not even used linux for a month before posting this question.

The issue happened because of Wine version 1.6 incompatibilities.

The solution is to update Wine.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `winecfg` you can set it to run all applications in a window. From http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=693292

> Applications --> Wine --> Configure Wine or just run winecfg from the
>   terminal
>
> Click on the Graphics tab Check the "Emulate Virtual Desktop" box And
>   enter in the virtual Desktop size (like 800x600 or something).

It sounds like your pygame application is setting a resolution and switching to fullscreen. If you could disable fullscreen in the pygame app, this would probably also work.

Comment: probably should've mentioned my app is windowed..
I'll try a virtual desktop and see what happens :)

Comment: ok, that works, but I'm trying to avoid this problem with other users, so it's more of a work-around than a solution.